# Can I delete "WINRE_DRV" OEM Partition if I only want to install Ubuntu and Not dual Boot?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lenovo

I want to replace Windows 10 and Install Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 330. I want to make use of the Complete hard drive and want to delete "WINRE_DRV" partition .

Can I do that without worrying about anything?

Answer (score 0):

don't pre-partion.

the installer is perfectly capable of doing this and it's made really **really** easy too.

way easyer than whatever you were about to do

Just run the ubuntu install process and when you reach this step select this :

[image: choice to select erase disk and reinstall]

this will give you the exact result you are looking for.

Comment: Just understand that this option deletes all existing partitions, including any data partition like D: drive. Copy any important files, documents, photos, music, etc. in external media if you want to keep them.